# Trying to replaceChildNode with node in different .scn file, why isn't it working?

Tags: swift, scenekit, scnnode

I am trying to replace a node in my main .scn with another in a different .scn file.
I've found the method which is

```
 func replaceChildNode(_ oldChild: SCNNode, 
                 with newChild: SCNNode)
```

but when I implement it. in my code, I get 1 warning and 2 errors:

```
warning= Expression implicitly coerced from 'SCNNode?' to 'Any'

error= 1.expected seperator (after with), 2.use of unresolved identifier 'with'.
```

even after error one fix 1 still get error 2 and the warning

I have defined my nodes the following way:

```
 var scene:SCNScene!
 var test3Scene:SCNScene!
```

in the loader it becomes:

```
 scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/x1.scn")
 test3Scene=SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/test3.scn")
```

and the concerned function looks like this:

```
   @objc func buttonClicked(){
      print("clicked")
      sceneView.allowsCameraControl  = false
      if(selection=="avatar"){
        scene.rootNode.replaceChildNode(_, oldChild: scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "test1 reference", recursively: true),
                                        with  newChild: test3Scene.rootNode.childNodes[0])
}


//scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "test1 reference", recursively: true) being the oldChild
//test3Scene.rootNode.childNodes[0] being the new one
```

Can anyone help on making this work? Thanks for your time

Comment: You should let Xcode autocomplete the method you’re typing because this part “replaceChildNode(_,” makes no sense. You’ll also need to unwrap your nodes before using them in that function.

Comment: even when autocompleting warning 1 and error 2 till shows, this is the link of the method in question https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408002-replacechildnode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `childNode(withName:recursively:)` method returns an optional (`SCNNode?`) but `replaceChildNode(_:with:)` expects an `SCNNode`.

You need to unwrap the optional before using it in the call.

---

Additionally there are issues where both the argument labels and parameter names are used at the call site. This isn't valid. See [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166).

```
scene.rootNode.replaceChildNode(_, oldChild: A
                                with newChild: B)
```

should be

```
scene.rootNode.replaceChildNode(A,
                                with: B)
```

Comment: your answer tackles the warning, I have tried unwrapping but maybe I am not doing it well, could you show me how you would write it if possible. Sorry I just started coding in swift

Comment: I updated my answer for the syntax error when calling `replaceChildNode(_:with:)`

Comment: thanks for the answer, it seems. like the syntax is correct, the only problem is that it's removing the node and considers is the replacement as nil. Even when replacing it with.  a node in the same scene I get a sigabrt error